# Component use only InvokeAsync method. There isn't synchronous pure Invoke method

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

It very odd for me, Razor give only synchronous Invoke  for View Components in particular project.In other project I have access to pure Invoke method. I assume the difference comes from dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component.Invoke is removed for the newest versions of .net Core And parameter collection is replaced by anonymous object. 
We should use view components that way :

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("ComponentName", new {param=value })
```